# How I Make Concurrence In A Wait Process Wcf On Iss 8.0?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, concurrency

I´m working on an wcf service to be hosted in an IIS 8.0 the service look like:

Interface:

```
namespace MCDWebService
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMCDService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Respuesta CapturarHuellas(string serialDispositivo);

}

[DataContract]
public class Respuesta
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Parametro Parametros { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }

    public Respuesta(string codigo, Parametro datos)
    {
        Codigo = codigo;
        Parametros = datos;
    }

    public Respuesta(string codigo, string mensaje)
    {
        Codigo = codigo;
        Mensaje = mensaje;
    }

}
}
```

the idea is that the method "CapturarHuellas" connect asyc to a socket server and wait for the response event, it look like this:

```
namespace MCDWebService
{
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall ) ]
public class MCDService : IMCDService
{
    private SolicitudMCD solicitudMCD;
    private System.Threading.EventWaitHandle eventoSocket;
    private Respuesta respuesta;


    public Respuesta CapturarHuellas(string serialDispositivo)
    {
        try
        {
            eventoSocket = new System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(true, System.Threading.EventResetMode.AutoReset);
            solicitudMCD = new SolicitudMCD(IPAddress.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IP_MCD")),
                int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Puerto_MCD")), serialDispositivo);
            solicitudMCD.Mensaje += solicitudMCD_Mensaje;

            eventoSocket.Reset();

            solicitudMCD.Solicitar();

            if (eventoSocket.WaitOne(50000)) // here wait the average waiting time is 10 seconds
            {
                return respuesta;
            }
            else
            {
                return new Respuesta("MCD_003_010", "Se alcanzó el tiempo máximo de respuesta del MCD.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Respuesta("MCD_003_000", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            eventoSocket.Dispose();
            solicitudMCD = null;
        }
    }

    void solicitudMCD_Mensaje(object sender, MensajeEventArgs e)
    {
        respuesta = new Respuesta(e.Codigo, e.Template);
        eventoSocket.Set();
    }
}
}
```

when I use this service on localhost and the client is also in localhost it has a concurrency of 100% answered requests, but when I take the service to a new machine with the same hardware  the concurrency effectiveness  drops to 19% answered requests.
I don´t know if its something of the service or a configuration in the iis.

Thanks
Drugdu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not in the server was in the client you must add the following code in the app.config

```
<system.net>
   <connectionManagement>
      <clear/>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="1000" />
   </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```